# Reactable conditional formatting one column text color based on another columns

Tags: r

I want a columns values to be different colors depending on a value in another column using reactable. This is the code I use but it doesn't change the color of the text so i am doing something wrong and would appreciate some help with this.

```
library(reactable)

iris %>% 
  reactable(columns = list(
    Sepal.Length = colDef(
      style = function(index){
        if(iris$Species[index] == "setosa"){
          color <- "red"
        }else if(iris$Species[index] == "versicolor"){
          color <- "yellow"
        }else if(iris$Species[index] == "virginica"){
          color <- "green" 
        }
      }
    )))
```

Answer (score 4):

This could be achieved like so:

1. To pass the row index make your style function a two-argument function.
2. Return the style information as a list.

Note: I make use of a simplified version of `iris`:

```r
library(reactable)

iris1 <- iris[c(1:2, 51:52, 101:102), ]

reactable(iris1, columns = list(
  Sepal.Length = colDef(
    style = function(value, index) {
      if (iris1$Species[index] == "setosa") {
        color <- "red"
      } else if (iris1$Species[index] == "versicolor") {
        color <- "yellow"
      } else if (iris1$Species[index] == "virginica") {
        color <- "green"
      }
      list(color = color)
    }
  )
))
```

[image]